# JavaScript Integer Leading to NaN

Tags: javascript, variable-types

I have JavaScript that basically looks like the following

```
function a() {
    b(1);
}

function b(myNumber) {
    c(myNumber);
}

function c(myNumber) {
    var calculation = 5 * (myNumber - 1);
    alert(calculation);
}
```

When I call the function `a()`, the alert box ends up saying "NaN". Why is this happening? I've tried using the `parseInt()` function in a number of places, but nothing seems to work.

## EDIT

Full code (what's actually being done rather than a stripped down example):

```
function updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId) {
    updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId, 1);
}

function updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId, pageNumber) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rowsPerPageSelect = document.getElementById(rowsPerPageSelectId);
    var rowsPerPage = rowsPerPageSelect.options[rowsPerPageSelect.selectedIndex].text;

    updateTable(table, rowsPerPage, pageNumber);
    //updateTablePageLinks();
}

function updateTable(table, rowsPerPage, pageNumber) {
    var tableRows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var totalNumberOfRows = tableRows.length;

    var startRow = rowsPerPage * (pageNumber - 1);      
     var endRow = Math.min(startRow + rowsPerPage, totalNumberOfRows - 1);

    alert("Start: " + startRow + "\nEnd: " + endRow);
}
```

A select box has an `onchange` calling `updateTablePagination('myTableId', 'rowsPerPage')`. The ids are both correct.

"Start" and "End" are both NaN.

## Edit 2

Alternatively, if I just do `alert(pageNumber)`, it is undefined.

## Simplified

Even this says `pageNumber` is undefined:

```
function updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId) {
    updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId, 1);
}

function updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId, pageNumber) {
    alert(pageNumber);
}
```

Comment: I just tested and I get 0. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/pqsVt/

Comment: I get `0` on Chrome. What browser?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the example you've posted.  You need to post the rest of your code.

Comment: We will need to see the actual code. The error doesn't happen in the code you posted above.

Comment: For me on the latest FF it alerts 0.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer.

Comment: When I execute that code in Chrome or IE it simply displays 0, so a bit more context might be required. :)

Comment: The above code will not alert "NaN", so it's not particularly useful. In your original code, there is at least one operation which returns NaN... you have to find that operation.

Comment: actually, it always alerts `0` even if you try `a(5)` for example

Comment: I will edit and add the full code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two functions called `updateTablePagination`.  Javascript does not support function overloading.  Get rid of the first declaration, because it is getting overwritten with the second.  You can use the `||` to define a default value for the parameter.

```
function updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId, pageNumber) {
    pageNumber = pageNumber || 1; //Set a default value for pageNumber
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rowsPerPageSelect = document.getElementById(rowsPerPageSelectId);
    var rowsPerPage = rowsPerPageSelect.options[rowsPerPageSelect.selectedIndex].text;

    updateTable(table, rowsPerPage, pageNumber);
    //updateTablePageLinks();
}


updateTablePagination(tableId, rowsPerPageSelectId) //Will call the function with pageNumber == 1
```

Comment: For example, x will either be blank or an integer. How does || work with integer comparison?

Comment: `pageNumber || 1` will return `pageNumber` if it is defined, and `1` otherwise.  Here is a really simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asYBp/

Comment: Dennis's description of || is almost correct. It doesn't return pageNumber if pageNumber is defined, and the nubmer 1 otherwise. It will return pageNumber if the value is "truish". This means if it's an integer value it will not do what you expect for the value 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're overwriting functions. With this:

```
function a() {
    a(1)
}

function a(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```

calling `a` will always call the second (overwritten) function and thus `x` is always undefined. You want something like overloading. Best thing to do in that case is using the `||` operator for a default value:

```
function a(x) {
    var x = x || 1; // x if x is given, otherwise 1
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: @Rachel G.: Usually you use it for booleans. `||` returns the left-side thing if it's 'truthy' and otherwise it returns the right-side thing. `true` is truthy and `false` is falsy so it works for booleans. Since some other values are falsy as well (`undefined` for example), doing `undefined || 1` will return `1`.

Comment: For example, x will either be blank or an integer. How does || work with integer comparison?

Comment: @Rachel G.: Falsy values are `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` and `false`; truthy is everything else.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the help. It was a toss up between you and pimvdb. Had to choose. Sorry.

Comment: @Rachel G.: I don't mind :) Dennis gave a more concrete solution in fact.